# Converting date timestamp into date in snowflake

Tags: date, format, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to work with the date (timestamp to be precise) and getting into trouble. My requirement is below.

I have a stage table where the data is stored as JSON in a Variant Column and the data looks like below in that column.

{
“message_body”: {
“campus_code”: “TEST”,
“campus_name”: “TEST”,
“event_type”: “TEST”,
“location_code”: “A00000”,
“location_name”: “TEST”,
“order”: {
“credit_total”: 0,
“app_version”: “1.0.9”,
“asap”: 1,
“complete_datetime”: “2020-11-19 00:08:20”
}
“timezone_offset_minutes”: -360,
}
}

I have below requirement

Convert the Datetime into only Date, so i tried the 2 below queries

1. select trunc(to_date(body:message_body:order:complete_datetime), 'DAY') FROM "stage_table";
2. select date_trunc('DAY', to_date(body:message_body:order:complete_datetime)) FROM "stage_table";

The source date is  "2020-11-19 00:08:20" and both the queries return the output as "2020-11-19 00:00:00" even though my expected value should be in the form of "YYYY-MM-DD".

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks

Aravind N

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of where you see the date displayed like that? Both queries should work as expected

Comment: The session for was altered for the  output datetime with a format other than "YYYY-MM-DD" and hence it was displaying the format with timestamp even after the conversion. I changed the session to have the default format as "YY-MM-DD" and now i see the conversion working properly. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To convert date in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029727/to-convert-date-in-snowflake)

Comment: Yes. it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of using :: to cast values to other types.  I was able to get this working with a similar nested JSON field in my own Snowflake instance.  Here is my attempt to adapt for your use case:

```
select body:message_body:order:complete_datetime::date
from "stage_table"
```

Comment: @Rajni — you should mark this answer as correct!